# asp.net core asp identity get username from string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net core MVC project and I am using Identity.  I have a Comment object and upon Create of a new Comment I save the currently logged in user's Id in a column in my table as a string.  It is working fine but ...

On my Details View I loop through each Comment in my collection and I want to display the username of the user that created the Comment, but all I have is the string that contains the user Id.

How do I get the username from this string in my Details View?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query the user by their ID.  Since this page already has the userId than do this...

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

var userProfile = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I put this in a separate method in my Repository class.  I just looped through my collection and replaced the CreatedBy property values with userProfile.UserName and it worked great.  Thanks again!